# ¿Cómo simplificar este código?

Tags: javascript

Simplificar este ladrillo de código.

Sirve para cambiar de color un botón a rojo y dejar todos los demás verdes habiendo 4 botones.

```
function cambiarColor1() {
    document.getElementById("boton1").style.backgroundColor = "#FF0000";
    document.getElementById("boton2").style.backgroundColor = "#15FF00";
    document.getElementById("boton3").style.backgroundColor = "#15FF00";
    document.getElementById("boton4").style.backgroundColor = "#15FF00";
}

function cambiarColor2() {
    document.getElementById("boton1").style.backgroundColor = "#15FF00";
    document.getElementById("boton2").style.backgroundColor = "#FF0000";
    document.getElementById("boton3").style.backgroundColor = "#15FF00";
    document.getElementById("boton4").style.backgroundColor = "#15FF00";
}

function cambiarColor3() {
    document.getElementById("boton1").style.backgroundColor = "#15FF00";
    document.getElementById("boton2").style.backgroundColor = "#15FF00";
    document.getElementById("boton3").style.backgroundColor = "#FF0000";
    document.getElementById("boton4").style.backgroundColor = "#15FF00";
}

function cambiarColor4() {
    document.getElementById("boton1").style.backgroundColor = "#15FF00";
    document.getElementById("boton2").style.backgroundColor = "#15FF00";
    document.getElementById("boton3").style.backgroundColor = "#15FF00";
    document.getElementById("boton4").style.backgroundColor = "#FF0000";
}
```

Comment: Deja cuatro espacios delate de cada linea para que se reconozca como `código`.

Comment: si lo que quieres es simplificar c'odigo usa el plugin `Jquery` que es para eso. de esa manera acortas todas las funciones de `javascript`.

Comment: En teoría se refería a acortar la lógica...

Comment: Pista: funciones con parámetros.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 1):

puede replazar todo de eso código con este

```js
function cambiarColor(numero) {
    for (let i = 1; i <=4; i++)
        document.getElementById("boton"+i).style.backgroundColor =
            (i==numero ? "#FF0000" : "#15FF00");
}
```

y en vez de usar `cambiarColor1()`, `cambiarColor2()`, etc.
use `cambiarColor(1)` o `cambiarColor(2)`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Siempre que veas código repetido o muy parecido, huele a que puedes reutilizarlo.

Intenta utilizar constantes en lugar de valores literales.

Desarrolla en inglés (esto no simplifica pero es bueno acostumbrarse)

```
function highlightButton(button, buttons) {
  buttons.foreach((b) => {
    document.getElementById(b).style.backgroundColor = b === button ? "#FF0000" : "#15FF00";
  });
}
```

Esto podría ser llamado así

```
buttons = ["boton1", "boton2", "boton3", "boton4"]
highlightButton("boton1", buttons)
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crear una función y llamar deacuerdo a lo que necesitas
Te dejo un Ejemplo:

```js
function cambiarColor(boton,color) {
    document.getElementById(boton).style.backgroundColor = color;
}
```

```html
<button  onclick="cambiarColor('botonprueba','blue')" id='botonprueba'>Cambiar color a Azul</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.button').on('click', function(){
     $('.button').css({'background':'#0f0'});
     $(this).css({'background':'#f00'});
   });
});
```

```css
.button{
  border: 0.1px, solid, #c0c0c0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #0f0; 
  padding: 2px 10px;
}
li{
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
   <li><button class="button">Hola</button></li>
   <li><button class="button">Hola</button></li>
   <li><button class="button">Hola</button></li>
   <li><button class="button">Hola</button></li>
</ul>
```

Sin Jquery ser'ia algo así:

```js
function cambiar(){
  var elem = document.getElementsByClassName("button");
  elem.addClass = "verde";
  this.addclass = "rojo";
}
var el = document.getElementsByClassName('button');
  el.onclick(cambiar());
console.log(a);
```

```css
.button{
  border: 0.1px, solid, #c0c0c0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #0f0; 
  padding: 2px 10px;
}
li{
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
}
.rojo{
  background: #f00;
}
verde{
  background: #0f0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
   <li><button class="button">Hola</button></li>
   <li><button class="button">Hola</button></li>
   <li><button class="button">Hola</button></li>
   <li><button class="button">Hola</button></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

suponiendo que utilizas la misma clase para los botones podrias hacer esto:

```js
// Aca seleccionamos todos los elementos de la clase "X" y el callback para poder manipular cada elemento
function iterateButtons(className, callback) {
  document.querySelectorAll(className).forEach(callback);
}


// Funcion que dado el indice del boton le cambia el estilo
function changeColor(activeIndex){
  const callback = (el, index) =>
        el.style.backgroundColor = index == activeIndex ? "#FF0000" : "#15FF00";
  iterateButtons(".btn", callback);
}

// Le agregamos a cada boton de clase "action" el evento onclick para que cambien de color
function SetupClick() {
  const callback = (el, index) =>
    el.onclick = () => changeColor(index);
  iterateButtons(".action", callback);
}

// ejecutamos el metodo para que agregue los eventos
SetupClick()
```

```html
<button class="btn"> boton 1</button>
<button class="btn"> boton 2</button>
<button class="btn"> boton 3</button>
<button class="btn"> boton 4</button>

<br/><br/><br/><br/>


<button class="action"> color 1</button>
<button class="action"> color 2</button>
<button class="action"> color 3</button>
<button class="action"> color 4</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que se podría simplificar usando uns única función con un parámetro tipo lista de pares id-color.
Vamos esto,

```
function cambiarColor(botones)
{
for(i = 0; i< botones.length; i++){
    document.getElementById(botones[i][0]).style.backgroundColor = botones[i][1];
    }
};
cambiarColor([['boton1', '#f0f0f0'],['boton2', '#FF0000'], ['boton3', '#15FF00'], ['boton4','#15FF00']]);
cambiarColor([["boton1", "#15FF00"],["boton2", "#FF0000"], ["boton3", "#15FF00"], ["boton4", "#15FF00"]]);
cambiarColor([["boton1", "#15FF00"],["boton2", "#15FF00"], ["boton3", "#FF0000"], ["boton4", "#15FF00"]]);
cambiarColor([["boton1", "#15FF00"],["boton2", "#15FF00"], ["boton3", "#15FF00"], ["boton4", "#FF0000"]]);
```

Así sin, ahondar mucho creo que puede valer. Claro que también podrías poner los valores de colores en el propio botón con datas sets y pasas la complejidad al HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Veo varios puntos de mejora:

- Crea funciones acotadas y reutilizables. Repetir trozos de código  todo el rato puede llevarnos a cometer errores. Si encapsulamos esa lógica en una función y además aportamos semántica ahorraremos líneas de código y simplificaremos la lectura del mismo. Sigue el principio DRY (Don't repeat yourself)
- Añade semántica a tus funciones y variables. Esta es la parte más complicada, pero como programadores tenemos que hacer un esfuerzo. En el código, la función "cambiarColor2" revela la intención a medias. "cambiarColor1, cambiarColor2, etc" me parecen nombres un poco pobres.

Te planteo el siguiente refactor:

```js
// Función reusable y con semántica (Revela la intención) tanto el nombre de la función como los parámetros
const changeButtonColor = (buttonId, color) => document.getElementById(buttonId).style.backgroundColor = color

// Crea abstraciones cuando veas un patrón claro (Al menos 3 casos de uso)
// En este caso asumimos que siempre vamos a tener que estilar estos 3 botones
const applyButtonTheme = (theme) => {
  const buttonIds = [
    'boton1',
    'boton2',
    'boton3',
  ]
  
  buttonIds.forEach((id) => changeButtonColor(id, theme[id]))
}

// Simplifica el código con "configuración"
const purpleTheme = {
  boton1: 'purple',
  boton2: 'darkblue',
  boton3: 'blue'
}

// Reúsalo
const setButtonsPurpleTheme = () => applyButtonTheme(purpleTheme)

// const setButtonsRedTheme = () => applyButtonTheme(redTheme)
// const setButtonsDarkTheme = () => applyButtonTheme(darkTheme)
// const setButtonsLightTheme = () => applyButtonTheme(lighTheme)
// ...


setButtonsPurpleTheme();
```

```css
button {
  border: none;
  padding: 4rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<button id="boton1">Boton 1</button>
<button id="boton2">Boton 2</button>
<button id="boton3">Boton 3</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Una método *simple*, es pasar el número de botón como parámetro de la función, y que esta resetee todos los botones y luego active el elegido.
Algo parecido a esto:

```js
function cambiarColor(n) {
    document.getElementById("boton1").style.backgroundColor = "#15FF00";
    document.getElementById("boton2").style.backgroundColor = "#15FF00";
    document.getElementById("boton3").style.backgroundColor = "#15FF00";
    document.getElementById("boton4").style.backgroundColor = "#15FF00";
    document.getElementById("boton"+n).style.backgroundColor = "#FF0000";
}
```

```html
<button id="boton1" onclick="cambiarColor(1)" style="background-color:#15FF00">1</button>
<button id="boton2" onclick="cambiarColor(2)" style="background-color:#15FF00">2</button>
<button id="boton3" onclick="cambiarColor(3)" style="background-color:#15FF00">3</button>
<button id="boton4" onclick="cambiarColor(4)" style="background-color:#15FF00">4</button>
```

Comment: Gracias, con lo poco que hemos visto en clase este código ahora lo entiendo. gracias a todos aunque no este a vuestro nivel

Answer (score 0):

Ya te pasaron unas cuantas opciones, aca te dejo la mia.

Podes seguir agregando botones siguiendo la logica de nombrado.

Espero que te sirvan, saludos.

```js
let botones = [1,2,3,4].map( n => document.getElementById( "boton" + n ) )

botones.forEach( (boton,index) => boton.onclick = () => cambiarColor(index) )

let color =  {rojo:"#FF0000",verde:"#15FF00"}

const cambiarColor = (nBoton) => botones.forEach( (boton, index) => 
    boton.style.backgroundColor = index == nBoton 
      ? 
        color.verde 
      : 
        color.rojo 
)

cambiarColor()
```

```html
<div>
  <button id="boton1"> Boton 1 </button>
  <button id="boton2"> Boton 2 </button>
  <button id="boton3"> Boton 3 </button>
  <button id="boton4"> Boton 4 </button>
</div>
```

Y aca tenes otra version mas, con css y mucho menos codigo.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach( 
  (b, bt, list) => b.onclick = () => 
    list.forEach( (b, i) => b.classList.toggle("verde", i == bt) ) 
)
```

```css
button {
  background-color: #FF0000;
  color:white;
}

.verde {
  background-color: #15FF00;
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button > Boton 1 </button>
  <button > Boton 2 </button>
  <button > Boton 3 </button>
  <button > Boton 4 </button>
</div>
```

Y aca tenes otra version mas, sin css y un poco menos codigo.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(
  ( b, bt, list ) => b.onclick = ( ) => 
    list.forEach( ( b, i ) => 
      b.style.backgroundColor = i == bt ? "#15FF00":"#FF0000" 
   ) 
)
```

```html
<div>
  <button> Boton 1 </button>
  <button> Boton 2 </button>
  <button> Boton 3 </button>
  <button> Boton 4 </button>
</div>
```